# Join Multiple Rows into 1 row different columns SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a query and would love some help.
I will provide a simplified version of the query in hopes that it communicates what I am attempting to do.

Given the following Tables:

- `TableA` (RecordNumber, TableAID, SomeValue)
- `TableB` (RecordNumber, X, Y, Z)
- `TableC` (RecordNumber, D, E, F, G)

The result set I am looking for:

```
TableB.RecordNumber, X, Y, Z, D, E, F, G, SomeValue1, SomeValue2, SomeValue3, SomeValue4
```

My query currently is

```
Select 
   TableB.RecordNumber, X, Y, Z, D, E, F, G, SomeValue1)
inner join 
   TableC on TableB.RecordNumber = TableC.RecordNumber
inner join 
   TableA on TableB.RecordNumber = TableA.RecordNumber
```

I realize that this is returning 1 row per SomeValue in TableA.

What I would like to do is combine each row for a `RecordNumber` into 1 row populating the `SomeValueX` with the `SomeValue` value from row X for that record number.

Thoughts?

Comment: Sql **requires** you to know the number of columns at the outset of the query. Your only option here is dynamic sql, that first asks TableA for how many possible `SomeValue` columns you need, and then uses that information to build a whole new sql string.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a variable number of columns without using dynamic SQL but you can have a variable number of comma-separated values in a single column.

```
SELECT b.RecordNumber, X, Y, Z, D, E, F, G, 
   STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + SomeValue 
        FROM TableA a
        WHERE a.RecordNumber = b.RecordNumber
        ORDER BY SomeValue
        FOR XML PATH('') 
        ), 1, 1, '') AS SomeValues
FROM TableB b
INNER JOIN TableC c
    ON b.RecordNumber = c.RecordNumber
```

If `TableA.SomeValue` is not of a character or string data type, you would also want to cast it to a varchar of an appropriate length.